# Confirm/warn dialog on back

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Like in the web browser, we have onBeforeUnload (vs onUnload) to show a alert or some warning "there is unsaved data - are you sure you want to go back".

I am trying to do the same. I couldn't find anything in the docs of react-navigation.

I thought of doing something real hacky like this, but I don't know if its the right way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'


export default function ConfirmBackStackNavigator(routes, options) {
    const StackNav = StackNavigator(routes, options);

    return class ConfirmBackStackNavigatorComponent extends Component {
        static router = StackNav.router;

        render() {
            const { state, goBack } = this.props.navigation;

            const nav = {
                ...this.props.navigation,
                goBack: () => {
                    showConfirmDialog()
                    .then(didConfirm => didConfirm && goBack(state.key))
                }
            };
            return ( <StackNav navigation = {nav} /> );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has also been discussed on their issue tracker: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3999 and https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation.github.io/issues/151

Comment: Thank you @LinusUnnebäck for sharing those links!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React navigation 5.7 has added support for it:

```
function EditText({ navigation }) {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(text);

  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        if (!hasUnsavedChanges) {
          // If we don't have unsaved changes, then we don't need to do anything
          return;
        }

        // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
        e.preventDefault();

        // Prompt the user before leaving the screen
        Alert.alert(
          'Discard changes?',
          'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
          [
            { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
            {
              text: 'Discard',
              style: 'destructive',
              // If the user confirmed, then we dispatch the action we blocked earlier
              // This will continue the action that had triggered the removal of the screen
              onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(e.data.action),
            },
          ]
        );
      }),
    [navigation, hasUnsavedChanges]
  );

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      placeholder="Type something…"
      onChangeText={setText}
    />
  );
}
```

Doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back

Answer (score 4):

On current screen set

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
  needUserConfirmation: true,
});
```

In your Stack

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = Stack.router.getStateForAction;
Stack.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  if (state) {
    const { routes, index } = state;
    const route = get(routes, index);
    const needUserConfirmation = get(route.params, 'needUserConfirmation');
    if (
      needUserConfirmation &&
      ['Navigation/BACK', 'Navigation/NAVIGATE'].includes(action.type)
    ) {
      Alert.alert('', "there is unsaved data - are you sure you want to go back", [
        {
          text: 'Close',
          onPress: () => {},
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirm',
          onPress: () => {
            delete route.params.needUserConfirmation;
            state.routes.splice(index, 1, route);
            NavigationService.dispatch(action);
          },
        },
      ]);
      // Returning null from getStateForAction means that the action
      // has been handled/blocked, but there is not a new state
      return null;
    }
  }

  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

Notes, 
Navigating without the navigation prop
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

NavigationService.js

```
function dispatch(...args) {
  _navigator.dispatch(...args);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished by displaying a custom back button in the header, and capturing the hardware back-event before it bubbles up to the navigator.

We'll first configure our page to show a custom back button by overriding the navigation options:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'

function showConfirmDialog (onConfirmed) { /* ... */ }

class MyPage extends Component {
  static navigationOptions ({ navigation }) {
    const back = <Button title='Back' onPress={() => showConfirmDialog(() => navigation.goBack())} />

    return { headerLeft: back }
  }

  // ...
}
```

The next step is to override the hardware back button. For that we'll use the package `react-navigation-backhandler`:

```
// ...
import { AndroidBackHandler } from 'react-navigation-backhandler'

class MyPage extends Component {
  // ...

  onHardwareBackButton = () => {
    showConfirmDialog(() => this.props.navigation.goBack())
    return true
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <AndroidBackHandler onBackPress={this.onHardwareBackButton}>
        {/* ... */}
      </AndroidBackHandler>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work though if we did a programatic back of a few steps and this was one of the pages in the stack.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the problem? Do you mean if you have navigated away from the page and then pop multiple pages in one step?

Comment: Sure thanks for asking. Screen 1 goes to Screen 2. Screen 2 has the warn on back. However from Screen 2 we open Screen 3 (a modal for instance). From Screen 3 we do `goBack(...)` or `popToTop()` so that it goes back to Screen 1. It should go back till Screen 2, and show the warning, and if agreed it should continue to go back to Screen 1.